# Focused on React Navigation TabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Key: React Native - React Navigation - TabNavigator

I don't understand how focused on TabNavigator works with "focused".

```
export default TabNavigator({
  Leaderboard: {
    screen: LeaderboardScreen
  },
  Game: {
    screen: GameScreen
  },
  Settings: {
    screen: SettingsScreen
  }
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Game',
  navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
    tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => {
      const {routeName} = navigation.state;
      let iconName;
      let labelName;
      switch (routeName) {
        case "Game":
          labelName = 'Game';
          iconName = "md-information-circle";
          break;
        case "Leaderboard":
          labelName = 'Leaderboard';
          iconName = "md-link";
          break;
        case "Settings":
          labelName = 'Settings';
          iconName = "md-options";
      }
      console.log(labelName, focused)
      return (
        <IconTextAnimation text={labelName} focused={focused}><Ionicons
          name={iconName}
          size={32}
          style={{
          marginBottom: -3
        }}
          color={focused
          ? Colors.tabIconSelected
          : Colors.tabIconDefault}/>
        </IconTextAnimation>
      );
    }
  }),
}
```

The console.log shows me the following each time I am on a new screen:

```
Leaderboard true
Leaderboard false
Game true
Game false
Settings true
Settings false
```

But the "focused" works properly for the color for example. So I really don't understand how this is working. Because the console.log says that everything is at the same state: false.

Comment: Did you eventually found out?

Comment: @Natim no sorry.